# Using user-space processes to assist kernel modules

Tags: linux, kernel

I'm working on one piece of a very high performance piece of hardware that works under Linux. We'd like to cache some data but we're worried about memory consumption - so the idea is to create a user process to manage the cache. That way, the cache can be in virtual memory, not in kernel space, et cetera.

The question is: what's the best way to do this? My first instinct is to have the kernel module create a character device file, and have a user program that opens that file, then sits on a select statement waiting for commands to arrive on it. But I'm concerned that this might not be optimal. A friend mentioned he knew of a socket-based interface, but when pressed he couldn't provide any details....

Any suggestions?

Comment: You might wanna consider looking at FUSE source...

Comment: Even better, you could look at CacheFiles and cachefilesd, intro here: http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/filesystems/caching/cachefiles.txt;hb=HEAD

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the [netlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netlink) interface. See [Why and How to Use Netlink Socket](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7356) [sic] for more information. Be careful of security issues when talking between the kernel and user space; there was a recent [vulnerability](http://lwn.net/SubscriberLink/329266/e127dc10e931bd66/) when `udev` neglected to check that messages were coming from the kernel rather than user space.

Comment: The recent vulnerability had a slightly different cause than what you stated: udev assumed that any netlink messages it was receiving originated in the kernel, but user processes could have maliciously sent messages to udev.

Comment: Will this have better performance than simply creating a character device?

Comment: I don't have any experience with using this myself; I've just heard of it, and since you were asking about a socket-based interface, I thought I'd mention it.